# How to structure a search list in Firestore?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to show a list of artists in my app which the user will be able to search through. I'm not sure however how to save this in Firestore?

First I created a collection "searchLists" with a document for each DJ but that means a *lot* of document reads so that's out of the question.

Now I created a document called "artists" which has a field "artistsDictionary" which contains all the artists.

```
| searchLists (collection)
   * artists (document)
      - artistsArray (array)
          0: (map)
            name: "Artist 0" (string)
          1: (map)
            name: "Artist 1" (string)
          2: (map)
            name: "Artist 2" (string)
```

And I retrieve and parse the array as followed:

```
let docRef = db.collection("searchLists").document("artists")
docRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
    if let document = document, document.exists {
        guard let documentData = document.data() else { return }
        let artistsDictionaryArray = documentData["artistsArray"] as? [[String: Any]] ?? []
        let parsedArtists = artistsDictionaryArray.compactMap {
            return SimpleArtist(dictionary: $0)
        }
        self.artistsArray = parsedArtists
    } else {
        print("Document does not exist")
    }
}
```

(SimpleArtist is a struct containing a "name" field.)

And I mean, it works, but I'm still new to Firestore and this seems kinda off. Is it? Or is this how I should/could do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> First I created a collection "searchLists" with a document for each DJ but that means a lot of document reads so that's out of the question.

This is the right approach, so you should go ahead with it.

> Why do I say that?

According to the official documentation regarding [modeling data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model) in a Cloud Firestore database:

> Cloud Firestore is optimized for storing large collections of small documents.

Storing data in an array is not a bad option but this is most likely used, let's say to store `favorite djs`. I say that because the documents have limits in Firestore. So there are some limits when it comes to how much data you can put into a document. According to the official documentation regarding [usage and limits](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas):

> Maximum size for a document: 1 MiB (1,048,576 bytes)

As you can see, you are limited to 1 MiB total of data in a single document. When we are talking about storing text, you can store pretty much but as your array getts bigger, be careful about this limitation.

Comment: I see, thanks! And ultimately I'd then add a listener to the collection so if a document gets added I don't have to get the whole collection again and it will just be 1 extra document read instead of all of them?

Comment: Is there a way to also not get the whole collection again after a user restarts the app? I could save all the documents in an array but the listener will of course be gone, could I like listen to all the documents except for those I have saved and update with that? Or would I at least require to listen to the collection on app launch?

Comment: For Android and iOS, [offline persistence](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline) is enabled by default. So this means that if there nothing has changed in the database, you get the data directly from cache. "could I like listen to all the documents except for those I have saved and update with that?" This is how Firestore works. If get only the new data and **not** the whole collection again.

Answer (score 2):

First off, Alexs' answer is 100% correct.

I want to add some additional data points that may help you in the long run.

The first item is arrays. Arrays are very challenging in NoSQL databases - while they provide a logical sequence data via the index, 0, 1, 2 they don't behave like an array in code - so for example; Suppose you wanted to insert an item at an index. Well - you can't (*you can but it's not just a simple 'insert' call). Also, you can't target array elements in queries which limits their usefulness. The smallest unit of change in a Firestore array field is the entire field - smaller changes to individual elements of a field can't be made. The fix is to not use arrays and to let FireStore create the documentID's for you data 'objects' on the fly e.g. the 'keys' to the node

The second issue - (which may not be an issue currently) is how the data is being handled. Suppose you release your app and a user has 2 million artists in their collection - with your code as is, all of that data is downloaded at one time which will probably not be the best UI experience but additionally, it could overwhelm the memory of the device. So working in 'chunks' of data it a lot easier on the device, and the user.

So I put together some sample code to help with that.

First a class to store your Artist data in. Just keeps track of the documentID and the artist name.

```
class ArtistClass {
    var docId = ""
    var name = ""

    init(aDocId: String, aName: String) {
        self.docId = aDocId
        self.name = aName
    }
}
```

and a class array to keep the artists in. This would be a potential dataSource for a tableView

```
var artistArray = [ArtistClass]()
```

This is to write an artist as a document instead of in an array. The documentID is a FireStore generated 'key' that's created for each artist.

```
func writeArtists() {
    let artistsRef = self.db.collection("artists")

    let floyd = [
        "name": "Pink Floyd"
    ]
    let zep = [
        "name": "Led Zeppelin"
    ]
    let who = [
        "name": "The Who"
    ]

    artistsRef.addDocument(data: floyd)
    artistsRef.addDocument(data: zep)
    artistsRef.addDocument(data: who)
}
```

and then function to read in *all* artists.

```
func readArtists() {
    let artistsRef = self.db.collection("artists")

    artistsRef.getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
        if let err = err {
            print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
        } else {
            for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                let docId = document.documentID
                let name = document.get("name") as! String
                let artist = ArtistClass(aDocId: docId, aName: name)
                self.artistArray.append(artist)
            }

            for a in self.artistArray { //prints the artists to console
                print(a.docId, a.name)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So your data in Firestore looks like this

```
artists (collection)
   8lok0a0ksodPSSKS
      name: "Let Zeppelin"
   WKkookokopkdokas
      name: "The Who"
   uh99jkjekkkokoks
      name: "Pink Floyd"
```

so then the cool part. Suppose you have a tableView that shows 10 artists at a time with a down button to see the next 10. Make this change

```
let artistsRef = self.db.collection("artists").order(by: "name").limit(to: 10)
```

Oh - and you'll notice the function of sorting now goes the server instead of the device - so if there's a million artists, it's sorted on the server before being delivered to the device which will be significantly faster.

You can also then more easily perform queries for specific artist data and you won't need to be as concerned about storage as each artist is their own document instead of all artists in one.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Awesome, thank you! That certainly helps understanding it. So I was on the right track before going off track. I'll do a Google search after posting the question but guess I could also ask you: is getting the documents with a limit of 10, for example, fast enough to handle scrolling in a table view?

Comment: @Bram-N Yes it is fast enough - in fact there's a of information about doing just that. It's called *infinite scroll* or *pagination*. There's a LOT of data here on SO on different ways to do that.